# Как обойти CORS во Front-End не используя cors-anywhere?

Tags: javascript, cors

Я сделал статистику по коронавирусу [ncov.dev](https://ncov.dev) и пока тестировал на локалке использовал плагин в браузере для отключения `cors`, но после деплоя у меня данные не загружались, крутился бесконечный спиннер, потом нашел решение (как по мне костыльное) использовать перед ссылкой на запрос “cors-anywhere”. Это решение работает но данные появляются с задержкой. Так же пробовал использовать `fetch` с опциональным параметром `no-cors`, это решение вообще не работат. Есть какой то способ обойти `cors` во front-end?

Comment: Никак. CORS именно для того и был изобретён, чтобы его нельзя было обойти.

Comment: проксировать запрос через свой сервер, других вариантов не будет. что в целом разумно, с реализацией кеширования. не каждый ведь запрос вы хотите таскать данные с удаленных серверов. Более того, даже проксировать не надо. по крону обновляйте все источники к себе, обрабатывайте, и потом уже с ними работайте.